# Swift, code style/format?

Tags: ios, swift

Now that if/for statements have enforced brackets for a code block I have been finding that short 1 line statements quickly start padding out the code. Is it acceptable to format these in a closure type fashion and present them as follows:

```
var physicsMarker = " "
if (eachChild.physicsBody != nil) { physicsMarker = "*" }
```

Or is this just going to leave those that look at my code going "What was he thinking" and instead I should stick with the more traditional:

```
var physicsMarker = " "
if (eachChild.physicsBody != nil) {
    physicsMarker = "*"
}
```

Comment: If you're working on a team, follow the code style guidelines that have been agreed upon. If you're asking for opinions, I always prefer the second.

Comment: Hi Ian, no team, just me, so I was curious about the opinions of others.

Comment: I prefer one line code if the intent is clear. It all depends on the readability. e.g. `let physicsMarker = eachChild.physicsBody != nil ? "*" : " "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the one line style frequently. I think it makes code cleaner and easier to read, especially if you are the only person on the project.

Another style that's similar:

```
if (eachChild.physicsBody != nil)
    { physicsMarker = "*" }
```

This calls attention to the identation and has a similar feel to python syntax.

To each his own!

Comment: Much appreciated Kris